# PHP shell_exec HOW TO CHANGE LINUX PASSWORD

Tags: php, shell-exec

I need some serious help guys. I got locked out from my sever: some hacker changed my password. However, he wasn't able to hack the root account. I still have access but it's not enabled in SSH, so I need access to my account in Linux. I only have access to HTTP on my server. I want to know whether it is possible to change my password by PHP.

I have the problem error message "sudo requires terminal". Can you please help me to recover my password.

```
<?
$command_exec = 'su root -u root mypwd';
$root_pwd = 'msiamd';
$description = array(
    0 => array("pipe","r"),
    1 => array("pipe","w"),
    2 => array("file","error-output", "a"
));
$process = proc_open($command_exec,$description,$pipes);
if(is_resource($process))
{
    fwrite($pipes[0],$root_pwd."\r\n");
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    print_R($pipes);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    proc_close($process);
}
?>
```

Comment: what other options i have with php to gain back access to my server thanks..

Comment: Is your host unwilling to physically access the server and enable root SSH login or re-passwd your login account?  To my knowledge, unless you have configured it differently beforehand, you can't make su or sudo not ask for the password interactively, expressly to discourage things like this (which could easily become security holes in the hands of poor programmers).

Comment: Are remote hands not available? Its easier to just boot straight into bash and make the adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
string shell_exec ('sudo su [[password]]');
string shell_exec ('passwd [[account]]');
string shell_exec ('[[new-password]]');
string shell_exec ('[[new-password]]');
```

**WARNING**
This is **untested** and **may not work/have unintended consequences!**  Use at your own risk!

I have only used shell_exec for a few simple things, never tried to do it with something like this.